# JavaScript DOM .remove() method removes other elements below it as well

Tags: javascript, dom

This is a model of an app that I am making. Essentially this is a to-do list and with a title and two buttons. One can change the colour of the list item and the other is supposed to remove the item.

Both the colour changing feature and the removing feature uses the exact same logic.

The problem is:

> The colour changing button successfully changes the colour of the item

> But The remove button removes every other element below it as well; it is supposed to just remove itself.

If I `style.display = "none"` it works, But I want to actually remove the element from existing. Not just hide it.

```js
let container = document.getElementById("container");
let button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let item = document.createElement("div");
    
    // Example title
    let title = document.createElement("P");
    let titleText = document.createTextNode("This is a test");
    title.appendChild(titleText);
    item.appendChild(title);
    
    //Remove Button
    let remove = document.createElement("A");
    let removeText = document.createTextNode("Remove");
    remove.appendChild(removeText);
    item.appendChild(remove);
    
    //ChangeColor button
    let color = document.createElement("H5");
    let colorText = document.createTextNode("Color");
    color.appendChild(colorText);
    item.appendChild(color);
  
    //Append the buttons and title to the parent element "item".
    container.appendChild(item);
    
    // Removing feature
    let removeButtons = document.getElementsByTagName("A");
    
    for (let i = 0; i < removeButtons.length; i++)
    {
      removeButtons[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
        removeButtons[i].parentElement.remove();
      })
    }
    
    //Color changing features
    let colorButtons = document.getElementsByTagName("H5");
    
    for (let i = 0; i < colorButtons.length; i++)
    {
      colorButtons[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
        colorButtons[i].parentElement.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      })
    }
})
```

```css
#container > * {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

a {
  color: red;
}

a:hover {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

h5:hover {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Add element</button>
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code loop through each buttons and remove their parent.

You can try add the remove event handler for the respective element when create and append.

```
remove.addEventListener('click', function(){
  this.parentElement.remove();
});
```

You can do the similar thing to add *color*.

```
color.addEventListener('click', function(){
  this.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
let container = document.getElementById("container");
let button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let item = document.createElement("div");
    
    // Example title
    let title = document.createElement("P");
    let titleText = document.createTextNode("This is a test");
    title.appendChild(titleText);
    item.appendChild(title);
    
    //Remove Button
    let remove = document.createElement("A");
    let removeText = document.createTextNode("Remove");
    remove.appendChild(removeText);
    item.appendChild(remove);
    remove.addEventListener('click', function(){
      this.parentElement.remove();
    });
    
    //ChangeColor button
    let color = document.createElement("H5");
    let colorText = document.createTextNode("Color");
    color.appendChild(colorText);
    item.appendChild(color);
    
    color.addEventListener('click', function(){
      this.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    });
  
    //Append the buttons and title to the parent element "item".
    container.appendChild(item);
    
})
```

```css
#container > * {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

a {
  color: red;
}

a:hover {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

h5:hover {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Add element</button>
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Comment: That is much smarter. Great, thank you! 

I can't see why my method removes the elements just below it
OR 
Why isn't it removing (just) its parent element, while the colouring successfully occurs?